# include headerfile from other library by using CMakeLists.txt in Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake

i want to use C++ Code in in my Android Project and I find out that Android Studio 2.2 support this much better than the old Version(debugging...).

I created a Folder for each Library so I can add all the C++ Files in the Folder to the Library.

Everything works fine, but there is a little Problem. I want to inlcude a Header File from library A into library B. 
I know in can simply use:

```
#include"../libraryB/someHeader.h"
```

in the cpp File in Library A. 
But is there a way that I can write

```
#include"somerHeader.h"
```

Here´s a part of my CMakeListsFile:

```
file(GLOB SOURCESLIB-A src/main/cpp/lib-A/*cpp)
file(GLOB SOURCESLIB-B src/main/cpp/lib-B/*cpp)

add_library(lib-A SHARED ${SOURCESLIB-A}
add_library(lib-B STATIC ${SOURCESLIB-B}

target_link_libraries(lib-A lib-B)
```

I'am using one CMakeLists.txt File.

Comment: you can try `include_directories(libraryB)` to add this folder to include search path globally, or `target_include_directories(...)` to include locally